# Design Pattern or suggestion for implementing

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, polymorphism, composition

## The Problem

A problem I keep running into again and again in C# is how to treat a class of things as the same in some contexts, but as different in different contexts. I have found some ways of handling this that I'm satisfied with for now, but this particular case I'm facing is leaving me unsatisfied.

I'm sure that defining an interface is the right way to go, as this allows me to treat very unlike things (nouns) as alike due to the verbs they expose (the interface implementation). But when at some point those things need to behave very differently, it becomes less clear to me. I'll try to give a concrete example and hope that you can suggest a way to design this well.

### The Application

The main application is essentially a workflow engine. It works with 3 different types of main objects, and has interfaces for:

1. Reading those objects in the ubiquitous language of the application (despite differences in different data sources) through implementations of `IDataSource`.
2. Creating a strongly-typed representation of those objects via specific consumers `IConsumer` which return `IConsumerMessage` items.
3. And turning those strongly-typed consumer messages into mostly string-typed `IRecipientMessage` representations in a kind of transport layer `IRecipient` (where the final step of serializing to CSV or XML or whatever can be performed by common libraries, so the recipient interface implementations don't need to concern themselves with the guts of this conversion, though they specify what is desired).

So to summarize, there can be many data sources, one or more of which can produce application objects of type `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, or `ObjectC`, which are then consumed by one or many `IConsumers` that each translate them into a particular `IConsumerMessage` representation, which are finally delivered to the actual real-world consumer companies these represent through a proximate recipient (a.k.a. a transport middleware) through one or more thin `IConsumerRecipientMessage` classes.

I'm happy with how all this is working. But now I need a generic way for some data lookups to be performed on the core application objects, and to manage the set of data needed by particular consumers.

## The Workflow Prompting This Question

Say `TrifidConsumer` has special rules for which of the `ObjectA` types it wants to see. There is a daily list of `ObjectA` model numbers that the Trifid company is interested in for each day, available by FTP. So at an appropriate step in the workflow, we need to take each core `ObjectA`, look up the date and model number in our `TrifidObjectADesirability` data that we've downloaded, and keep track of the resulting yes/no flag, for later consumption by the `TrifidConsumer` implementation of the `IConsumer` when deciding what `ConsumerMessage` items it will return to the core of the system.

### How This Workflow is Handled Now, and Desired Requirements

I'm refactoring an existing codebase, which currently is doing special logic in the core of the system on `ObjectA` types if it knows the consumer needs the special Trifid metadata. However, I think the application engine shouldn't know about the `TrifidObjectADesirability` data, and shouldn't know the difference between one consumer or another--this behavior should be able to be specified in a modular way, and be discovered or composed through some means so the engine is agnostic.

Additionally, on top of the normal workflow UI for processing objects of the different types, I need to present to the user a special management page where he can look at all presence or absence of loaded `TrifidObjectADesirability` data, see which dates are present, perhaps even manually look up a few values by model number, delete a particular date's data, force a fetch of a particular date, attempt a direct FTP pull of a date's data, upload a zip file of a date's data, or load a zip file from a predefined folder where a process has theoretically already downloaded such FTP data.

It is also possible that another consumer could want access to the `TrifidObjectADesirability` data and signal a desire to take a dependency on it (rather, on the *result* of its lookup for `ObjectA` objects), requiring a separation between the operation of the lookup and the consumption of it.

Finally, each new consumer that gets added could have its own set of data--perhaps instead of model number, it needs to perform some other lookup against color or size or some other attribute. It needs to have a set of data that is *handled* almost identically to the `TrifidObjectADesirability` data, but is different in its use and shape: It could be a lookup based on two fields on `ObjectB` items, that returns 3 fields that will need to be inspected later. Or this looked-up data could need to be hit against yet another data source before a final value can be determined.

## The Actual (tl;dr) Question

What is a pattern that could help me accomplish these summarized objectives/requirements?

1. Define many data sets and metadata for each one's management (along with UI tools) such that they can be treated generically by the core application (though using supporting classes from the core application is fine, as long as the proper nouns and the individual details of the different data sets are not accessed in the core application via special knowledge of the data set).
2. Those data sets and attendant methods and metadata need to be combined into some kind of `Enrichment` container object.
3. The `Enrichment` data set container object needs to expose generic methods for fetching data (both from the external source, and from the saved local store), removing data, and deleting portions of it based on different criteria, returning up to a million rows for a whole day's data, or hitting the primary data source to (re)load a day's data on demand, storing looked-up data into a permanent local store, or looking up just a few values' presence in the data. These methods nonetheless need to be able to be used in the specifics ways they are different where appropriate.
4. Each `IConsumer` can indicate it has a dependency on the result of one or more of these data sets.
5. in the workflow that can provide the needed data, so that each `IConsumer`, when it receives each `ObjectA`, receives it with the required enrichments present so it can perform the enrichment (ask the concrete `TrifidObjectADesirabilityEnrichment` if each `ObjectA` is present in it), or the core system has already (generically) performed the enrichment and the result is presented within the `ObjectA` itself in some kind of dictionary or data structure acessible by the `IConsumer`.
6. All enrichment actions need at least temporary caching so if another `IConsumer` asks the same question (perhaps Dufflepud company says it wants to use the same Trifid data, it can, and whichever corresponding `IConsumer` is handed the immutable `ObjectA` first actually triggers the lookup a single time) it can be answered again.

## Final Thoughts

One architecture with some similarities that comes to mind is ASP.Net MVC areas. They are like mini bolt-in web sites, that function in the context of a larger web sit as an integrated part of the whole that an external consumer can't tell was modularly applied, simply by being called during route and view-engine location registration.

P.S. I realize this question is very long, and I welcome ideas on how to make it shorter while still explaining the problem well enough to get a useful answer. I think this is an at least somewhat complex/tricky problem or I wouldn't have had to lay it all out like this, and I am very grateful for the time and energy of anyone who bothers to try to comprehend such a wall of text and make useful suggestions in response.

P.P.S. Solution dependency diagram (assume a transitive dependency throughout, except the web site and service do not depend on the DataSource, Consumers, or Recipients).

```
           Application
               ^
               |
            Business
               ^
      _________|__________
     /                    \
DataSource (1..n)     Consumers (1..n) & ConsumerMessages
     ^                    ^
     |                    |
     |                Recipients (1..n per Consumer) & RecipientMessages
     |                    ^
     \____________________/
               |
        CompositionRoot 
               ^
      _________|__________
     /                    \
     |                    |
 Web Site          Windows Service (perform automated tasks)
```

The dependencies are upward, in the sense that, e.g., the DataSource project has a reference to the Business and Application projects. The Business project gets its instances of `IDataSource` via the CompositionRoot, which for example instantiates each DataSource for this invocation of the application and passes them in as dependencies to the Business engine's main class constructor (and the same for each consumer and its paired recipients). A unit test can compose a different application, such as one with mocked dependencies, so it can actually unit test the core engine's behavior.

The composition root creates all needed dependency instances and combines them returning a composed Business-Application to the user of it (the web site, or windows service, or some future API or Windows Forms program or anything at all) for use. This can loosely be called poor man's DI, though not the kind that isn't DI at all (where you do `new Dependency()` inside of the class that needs it)—all dependencies are instantiated in a single, tiny class in the composition root whose only purpose is to compose the application and return it. The web site's IOC container/library can inject this composed application into controllers as necessary, but the service can also acquire the exact same composed application without having to repeat the construction of it via its own IOC container or other method.

I am thinking that I need to specify an `IEnrichment` interface in the business or application projects, somehow define how each different enrichment works in the DataSource or another (new) project, uniquely identify each concrete `Enrichment` via a ubiquitous language term such as an `EnrichmentIdentifier` that wraps a string indicating the ID of the enrichment, specify dependencies within each Consumer using an equatable instance of the same `EnrichmentIdentifier` string, and finally perform all these actions as described in the workflow above.

But I really am not sure, and sans working directly with folks who are experienced enough to help, I have turned to the P.SE community for help.

Comment: IMO this question is too broad. Could you please split it into several smaller, simpler questions, each one addressing one specific design issue? Even the _LT;DR;_ section is too verbose. And the _final thoughts_ section is even more verbose.

Comment: Dear @TulainsCórdova I can't see how this can be made shorter, because the problem is one that exists at a whole-system level. If I give a high-level overview with less detail, readers are unlikely to be able to suggest a useful approach. If I ask for each single requirement out of context, answers are unlikely to fit well with each other systematically. I regret that my post is too long for your taste, and I appreciate your taking the time to suggest that it is too broad and lengthy, but perhaps then my question simply *isn't for you*, and someone else with a different appetite can help me.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I don't find your voting to close (if it was you and not the other 3 people who have visited so far) to be helpful for such a young question—if the question is left open for 2 days, I can spend my own reputation to add a bounty, no skin off your nose, but if you close it people can't answer even if they desire! Consider that I would dearly love the advice of someone like you with 20 years of programming experience who is expert in "OOP, OOD, good practices, SOLID principles, software patterns and code quality". But let someone else answer if you won't/can't.

Comment: I think scope-specific questions have a better change to get useful answers, and if abstract enough, such answers' solutions can fall into place within the whole. As it is right now, one would have to ask dozens of questions in form of comments to understand the humongous scenario, spawning long discussiones below each attempt of answer. It takes a lot of commitment to read and digest the scores of business rules contained in that text-wall. Just trying to help improve the question.

Comment: Have you considered that my actual problem here could be *not knowing how to break up the problem space into smaller pieces*? That would mean your response is akin to "first, solve your real problem on your own, and *then* we can help you solve the easier sub-problems you may already know how to solve and don't need help solving!" How does that help me? Is the answer "your problem is just too hard for programmers.stackexchange, you'll have to pay real money for that level of help"? Know any experts in the Pacific Northwest that I can buy lunch for and would talk this over with me?

Comment: P.S. Attempting to honestly consider whether you're actually thinking I'm acting as a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) in this question: that is truly not my mindset. I really feel stuck and I don't know how to continue. I want to *learn*, not just solve this problem and go away. I would lay out real money to get expert help on it. I have [contributed materially](http://stackoverflow.com/users/57611/erike) to stackoverflow and other SE sites. I generally answer more questions than I ask, and I've been a member for almost 7 years. How do I figure this out?

Comment: I'll retract my close-vote.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I happened to be reading [Big Ball of Mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/) today and came across a quote I thought interesting: "Managing a large project is a qualitatively different problem from managing a small one, just as leading a division of infantry into battle is different from commanding a small special forces team. Obviously, 'divide and conquer' is, in general, an insufficient answer to the problems posed by scale." This resonated with me as exactly what I meant when I said that solving problems individually may not help so much with solving the overall system problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44893/discussion-between-tulains-cordova-and-erike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mindset is interfaces and it looks like that served you well so far. I am actually fairly impressed with the displayed analytical approach. It also seems you are stuck in this "interfaces can solve anything" dogma.

What I read is the need for a filter. An abstract base class Filter that implements IConsumerFilter with method Process(Object object) returning Object. If the returned object is null, there is no interest in the object. A non-null result will be the enriched object for the particular consumer. Each type of consumer gets its own Filter descendant that knows what type of input object it can expect and what type of result it should yield. The caller and receiver can validate the type and cast before proceding.

Who is to decide if an object is interesting or not? You, the system integrator? People at the consumer's site? Whoever this is needs to implement the Filter descendant or at least specify the criteria.
The filters may be implemented in a separate assembly. Are the filter criteria fixed, can they be hard coded? Filters may need to be updated on a regular basis or be dynamic, they could read a piece of xml that specifies the filter. When that is updated, the filter could re-initialize itself.

I hope this helps or may trigger a better idea to emerge.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm working on an implementation right now and when it has really settled down and is functioning, I'll report back and will upvote at that time.

Comment: I promised, and here's the invite and answer acceptance. Better late than never!